# Tomcat start up issue with version 9.0.12

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to deploy application on tomcat version 9.0.12 running with jre 1.8 and on Eclipse Oxygen.

But I am constantly running into the following exception,

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
```

I have a `servlet-api-2.5.jar` in my classpath which has the `getClassLoader` method. Not sure what I have done wrong.

Could someone please help me with a solution.

Comment: Looks like you haven't import the proper library. Give us your code. atleast the import statements

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala  import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;                                                                     I tried compiling and deploying with servlet-api-2.5.jar and javax.servlet.jar separately. But still end at the same exception.

Comment: @Bopanna if the below one is the answer to your question you can mark the question answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispite your claim the `ServletContext` from within your servlet-api-2.5.jar cannot have the method in question if it actually contains the servlet 2.5 specification as suggested by the file name.

`ServletContext.getClassLoader` was introduced in version 3.0 of the servlet specification:

```
/**
 * Get the web application class loader associated with this ServletContext.
 *
 * @return The associated web application class loader
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException    If called from a
 *    {@link ServletContextListener#contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)}
 *    method of a {@link ServletContextListener} that was not defined in a
 *    web.xml file, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with
 *    {@link javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener}. For example, a
 *    {@link ServletContextListener} defined in a TLD would not be able to
 *    use this method.
 * @throws SecurityException if access to the class loader is prevented by a
 *         SecurityManager
 * @since Servlet 3.0
 */
public ClassLoader getClassLoader();
```

As [Apache Tomcat 9 implements Servlet 4.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), you should not pollute your class path with different servlet api versions.

Tomcat already ships with the correct `servlet-api.jar` provided in `apache-tomcat/lib` directory. You should not add any version of that jar to your web application. If you are using maven, you can add a reference to servlet 4 api in `provided` scope, so your IDE and build tool knwo it will be available at runtime but must not be shipped with your artifacts:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or alternatively to exactly match chosen Apache Tomcat version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```